# wcf data service client failed on savechanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I'm developing an application base on client/server model using WCF data service.

But this is the third day that I have a problem and I'm searching for a solution. When I launch SaveChanges() method on the data context on the client side, the application failed and closed without throwing any error.

I don't understand the problem. My Data is accessible from reading with a navigator. This is my infrastructures :

- Visual Studio 2013
- EntityFramework 5.0
- Wcf Data Service 5.6.

Comment: Do you have any logging enabled?

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer? It might logged some error messages there.

Comment: Enable WCF tracing to find the exception. Usually it's a circular reference or a type that cannot be serialzied.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
It was a problem with entity validation.
But I want why there are no exception thrown and the application fail and close without any justification.
I will post an other question about it.
thank you for your consideration.